# Make a div full height when scrolling

Tags: html, css

What is the trick to have a div 100% height always, even if the user is scrolling ?

I try this but it didn't work the height is only applied to the active window.

```
<body>  
     [...]
     <div class="popup_container">...</div>
</body>

.popup_container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; /** even this didn't work **/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 12;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.popup_container {
    position: fixed;
```

Change position to fixed. That should fix your problem ;)

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bHAc/)

Comment: and if you want it to scroll add a `bottom: 0;` with a `position: relative` on parent: http://jsfiddle.net/6bHAc/1/

Comment: thanks it's work now :) but with `position: absolute;` there is no solution ? also if you try to watch a picture on your facebook you will notice that scrolling bar is disappear ! how facebook can make that ?

Comment: thanks @Marcel but I don't want to specify a height for my `body` i want it to be auto.

Comment: @Youssef facebook has some broken stuff, but if you want elements positioned on a certain spot when you scroll other content it might be better to make the scrollable content actually scrollable instead of making everything else stick. And as for scrollbars to appear and disappear you can easily add a simple hover state, for example: `class { overflow:hidden; }` and `class:hover { overflow: auto; }`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/MXz2E/ (hover over black box)

Comment: for my case even if i put `{ overflow:hidden; }` the scroll yes disappear but I can scroll.